# Accessing Beyond the malloc()'d Memory

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

My question is when I allocate memory for go variable as in the following code I can reach the area which I didn't allocate ( in this case after the first one). So what is the limit of this top reaching point because when I try to print or access thousandth place I get an segmentation error. How does OS(Ubuntu 18.04) limiting this area ?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int *go=NULL;
    go = malloc(sizeof(int)*1);
    *go = 190;
    *(go+1)=20;
    *(go+2)=-13;
    *(go+3)=450;
    *(go+4)=140;
    *(go+5)=190;
    printf("%d\n",*(go));
    printf("%d\n",*(go+1));
    printf("%d\n",*(go+2));
    printf("%d\n",*(go+3));
    printf("%d\n",*(go+4));
    printf(">>>%d\n",*(go+5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this is undefined behavior.

Comment: "How does OS limiting this area?" - which OS exactly?

Comment: In this case Ubuntu 18.04.02

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.   On one system, even trying to access one past the end of the memory returned by `malloc()` may crash.  On another system, you may be able to go well past, because the implementation of `malloc()` over-allocates.   The behaviour may also change over time, on any particular machine, for example, due to how other processes use memory.

Comment: accessing memory that your application does not own is undefined behavior.  I.E. anything can happen.

Comment: OT: regarding: `go = malloc(sizeof(int)*1);`  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the `*1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Address space is allocated by the application from the OS.   These allocations have a granularity which is a function of the hardware, the operating system and the parameters to the malloc library.   Few architectures have bytewise granularity.

Malloc is not typically an operating system intereface, rather it is a highly usable library built upon less sophisticated mechanisms.  Malloc determines what granularity it wants to grow and shrink the address space by, and constructs data structures to track the memory at a size that is convenient to it.   For example, it might never return less than a 64byte object.   You *might be able to* determine this using realloc:  allocate a set of small objects (say 1 byte), and find the two addresses that are closest together, and call grow() below with the lower pointer and this difference.   It may be possible you have an unconventional malloc, and this won't work....

```
int grow(void *p, int maxdiff) {
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i < maxdiff; i++) {
        void *t = realloc(p, i);
        if (t != p) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

For a good tutorial on malloc(), read and understand the implementation of it in K&R's "The C Programming Language".